# How to implement the Debug trait for struct that has a trait object member?

Tags: rust, traits

My goal is printing the contents of struct that has trait object member but I can't find how to tell Rust compiler that the member also implements other traits like `Display` or `Debug`.

For example, in the following program, I want to print the structure of `S2` (and `S1` for comparison) but I get stuck in the implementation of `fmt`.

```rust
trait Tr {}

impl Tr for usize {}

impl Tr for String {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S1<A: Tr + std::fmt::Debug> {
    member: Box<A>,
}

struct S2 {
    member: Box<Tr>,
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for S2 {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        // ??
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = S1 {
        member: Box::new(String::from("abc")),
    };

    println!("{:?}", s1);

    let s2 = S2 {
        member: Box::new(String::from("abc")),
    };

    println!("{:?}", s2);
}
```

My desired output of this program is

```
S1 { member: "abc" }
S2 { member: "abc" }
```

Is it possible to implement `Debug` for a struct like `S2`?

(Rust version: 1.35)

Comment: `T` is a bad name for a trait, because if I see `Box<T>` I expect `T` to be a generic type parameter that has been provided via the struct, e.g. `struct S2<T> {}`. should be something longer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement `Debug` for a struct like `S2`?

Yes you can, and this is clearly pointed out in the [Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html)

You need to implement the `Debug` trait for your `S2` like following:

```
trait MyTrait {}
impl MyTrait for usize {}
impl MyTrait for String {}

trait MyTraitWritable: MyTrait + Debug {}
impl MyTraitWritable for usize {}
impl MyTraitWritable for String {}

impl std::fmt::Debug for S2 {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(fmt, "S2 {{ member: {:?} }}", self.member)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0129104923b5110927e2eb0722e2db68)

Comment: *`Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`* — it's customary to just use `std::fmt::Result`.

Comment: @Shepmaster, revised the answer regarding your comments

Comment: It's customary to provide a blanket impl of `MyTraitWritable`; something like `impl<T: MyTrait + Debug> MyTraitWritable for T {}` (as shown in the linked duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

You can make `S2` generic but you don't need to specify that the type should also implement `Debug` right there. Instead, you can specify it in the `impl`:

```
struct S2<A: Tr> {
    member: Box<A>,
}

impl<A: Tr + std::fmt::Debug> std::fmt::Debug for S2<A> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(fmt, "S2 {{ member: {:?} }}", self.member)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This way, `S2` will implement `Debug` if the actual type does.